# Remove unwanted string from retrofit response

Tags: android, json, exception, response, retrofit2

I want to remove string from my retorfit2 POST request response.

This is my **response**:

```
  /*-secure-{"response":{"response":{"response":{"token":"95a2c5a8","email":"xxx@sample.in","name":"xxx"},"status":true,"code":0.0},"status":200},"status":200}*/
```

Due to some security reason my server automatically adding the strings

`/*-secure-` and `*/`

beacuse of this , on converting to json I am getting below **error**:

```
 com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 2 path $
```

Comment: You might be able to implement a converter, which acts before the GsonConverter. It strips away that secure part at the beginning and end and then delegates the valid JSON rest to the actual Gson converter. Jake Wharton outlined a similar approach in his talk: https://youtu.be/t34AQlblSeE?t=27m28s

Comment: @peitek thanks Gson custom converter is working.

Comment: Can you post what you did in the end?

Comment: @FrankR check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My custom gson converter class

```
    final class CustomGsonResponseBodyConverter<T> implements Converter<ResponseBody, T> {
    private final Gson gson;
    private final TypeAdapter<T> adapter;
    private Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\/\\*-secure-\\W(.*)\\*\\/$");

    CustomGsonResponseBodyConverter(Gson gson, TypeAdapter<T> adapter) {
        this.gson = gson;
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    public T convert(ResponseBody value) throws IOException {
        String response = value.string();
        System.out.println(response);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(response);

        JsonReader jsonReader = gson.newJsonReader(new StringReader(matcher.group(1)));
        try {
            return adapter.read(jsonReader);
        } finally {
            value.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how to set this converter into retrofit

Answer (score 1):

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .setLenient()
    .build();
// ...
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)
```

Please see [this](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1676)

Comment: now the error message changed to
java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 2 column 318 path $